# Extend the Where method for IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I want to extend the `Where` to something like this: `.WhereEqual("Field", "SomeString")` wich must be equivalent to `.Where(p => p.Field== "SomeString")`, here is my code:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEqual<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string Field, string Value)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, Field);

        var val = Expression.Constant(Value);
        var body = Expression.Equal(prop, val);

        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);

        Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, typeof(bool) };

        var mce = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                "Where",
                types,
                exp
            );
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
    }
```

thanks to the debugger i can see that `exp` is set to `{p => (p.Field== "SomeString")}`, but the `Call` method throws the following exception :

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code, Additional
>   information: No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable'
>   is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type
>   arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic."

How can I give the `Where` the needed arguments ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not repost, edit and improve the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEqual<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string Field, string Value)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, Field);

        var val = Expression.Constant(Value);
        var body = Expression.Equal(prop, val);

        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);


        return System.Linq.Queryable.Where(q, exp);
    }
```